# .htaccess RewriteCond for https

Tags: .htaccess

We have our site setup and would like to have a secure members area.  (e.g.:  *https://www.abc.com/members/*).

Our host provides us an SSL URL to use for free though it isn't very pretty (*www1234.sslurl.com/abc/members/*).

Is it possible to use *https://www1234.sslurl.com/abc/members/* and rewrite the URL to read as *https://www.abc.com/members*?  If so, I'd appreciate some help with the rule to do this.

**Note:**  This is NOT for a shopping cart and we aren't storing credit cards, or social security numbers or anything sensitive like that.  We just want to provide users with a secure browser connection when logging in.  Is *rewriting* the URL unethical?

***Added details since someone voted to close my question though I'm not sure why.  This is a valid question and is tagged appropriately.***

================== SOME CODE I'VE BEGUN WORKING WITH==================

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc.com  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !abc/  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ abc/$1 [L]
```

Does this look right?

Comment: This is definitely not unethical. You really should be doing all logins over HTTPS.

Comment: @Kenzo True but I mean unethical rewriting the URL and keeping the free SSL URL instead of paying for their "premium" service.  :)

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. You should definitely get your own SSL certificate then, since there is no way to do that kind of rewrite on an SSL cert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there was a way to do this (and I don't believe that you Apache supports such a redirect), the browser would likely complain anyway. Typically SSL certificates only work for domain.com and www.domain.com. If you try to access that certificate using a different URL, your browser will give an error about the certificate not being trusted.

Comment: Thanks Nate.  That makes sense or cents, depending on how you want to read it.  :D